# Answered a question that I later realized is a duplicate

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

I have just [added an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851605/326036) to a question that, shortly after posting my answer, I realised is probably a duplicate of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146951/326036), as suggested in the comments, and I flagged it as such.
My answer overlaps partially with one of the answers in the duplicate target. What should I do with my answer? These options occur to me:

- Delete it from the (suspected) duplicate and repost it under the other question.
- Delete it altogether.
- Leave as is.
- Leave the current one *and* repost to the other one (editing in such a way to avoid the overlap).

Comment: Have you checked to see whether this question of yours is a duplicate? I would think that the situation you describe must have already come up some time before now.

Comment: I would also have thought so, but nothing came up in my search.

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer then.

Comment: Is "Leave as is and repost it under the other question" an option?

Comment: @peterwhy Yeah that should also be an option I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I ended up deleting my answer and posting it under a [new, self-answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852147/326036), and posting a link to it in a comment.
The reasons for this are:

- If I remove the overlap with the existing answer on the target duplicate, the rest of my answer is kind of beyond the scope of the original question.
- My answer answered a related, general question that is nonetheless not a strict generalization of the original question and I believe is interesting in its own right.
- I have looked for duplicates for my new question. There are many related posts, [a few](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32381/326036) [of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311450/326036) are concrete special cases, and [one is a generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3970351/326036), but none of them answer this question exactly.

Answer (score 7):

My vote goes to your first-listed option, but taking care to note the overlap with the earlier answer at the target.